# Express Recursive Relation as Series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider

$ y'' + xy'+x^2y = 0 $

Show that the ODE has a fundamental set of solutions y1(x), y2(x) with W(y1, y2)(0) = 1 and
y1(x) an even function and y2(x) an odd function.

I've solved it all the way until the recurrence relation but I'm not able to find a specific formula for the even/odd terms.

The Relevant Recurrence Relation is :

$$a_{k+2}=\frac{-ka_{k}-a_{k-2}}{(k+1)(k+2)} \forall k>=2 $$

Other facts :

$$a_{2} = 0 $$
$$a_{1} = -6a_{3} $$

Answer (score 0):

You do not need
to find an explicit formula
for the functions.

From
$a_{k+2}
=\frac{-ka_{k}-a_{k-2}}{(k+1)(k+2)}
$,
using $k=2$,
$a_4
=\frac{-2a_{2}-a_{0}}{12}
=\frac{-a_{0}}{12}
$.

If you choose
$a_0=0$
and
$a_1 \ne 0$,
you get a solution
$y_2(x)$ with
all odd exponents,
which is therefore an odd function.

If you choose
$a_0\ne 0$
and
$a_1 = 0$,
you get a solution
$y_1(x)$ with
all even exponents,
which is therefore an even function.

These are the solutions you seek.